# Pointer and inheritance in C - cast issue?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I'm working on an opengl project and I got a problem with some of my classes:

There are 3 main classes:

---

```
class scene{
public:
   scene();
   object** elements;
   unsigned int nb_elements;

   void add_object(object* _element){
       objet** p_elements=elements;

       while(p_elements-elements!=nb_elements)
           p_elements++;

      *p_elements=_element;                    //here is the bug
      nb_elements++;
    }


}
[...]
};
```

---

```
class object{
public:
    object();
    [...]
};
```

---

```
class point : public object{
point();
point(double _x, double _y, double _z,double _r);
[...]
}
```

---

I initialize the scene after initializing Opengl, in the same function:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL(){

   [OpenGL initialization]

   _scene=new scene;
   point* s1=new point(0.0,0.0,3.0,1.0);
   _scene->add_object(s1);

}
```

The bug is in the scene::add_object function. I don't understand why it doesn't work since *p_elements and _element are both pointers. I gues it's a cast problem but I don't know how to fix it. I tried dynamic cast: the bug remains.

Thank you for your help,

Kamouth

Comment: Why is this tagged as C? C and C++ are two totally different languages

Comment: Have you allocated memory for `elements`?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII precisely. I presume the C refers to the code you can witness in `add_object` (and `nb_elements` in general). This is _not_ typical C code. The fact that you can ssee a class keyword doesn't make it 'C++' to me

Comment: No I haven't... I'm shameful.. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objet** p_elements=elements;` sets `p_elements` to uninitialized memory. So `p_elements-elements!=nb_elements`, `p_elements++;` and `*p_elements=_element;` invoke undefined behavior. I'm not going to advise you to initialize the memory, but merely to **use `std::vector`** and smart pointers instead.

The double pointers suggest you come from a C background, but if you want to do C++ development you have to learn C++ idioms. Don't stick to writing C code in C++.

Comment: Hi, I used double pointers because I use a virtual function which need to be called through pointer (am i right ?).

Comment: Surely not if `elements` has been allocated in a constructor. This is an off-by-one error, since `p_elements` will be pointing past the end of the `elements` array when the loop has completed, assuming `nb_elements` is set correctly.

Comment: Actually, given the `nb_elements` at the end, it's more of a "you haven't allocated enough memory" error. To echo @LuchianGrigorie though, try to use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Kamouth no. You can call virtual functions through smart pointers and references as well.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore, Ok, but i can't use std::vector right ? I've no idea what smart pointers are.

Comment: @Kamouth well then, this is the perfect time to learn. Sure you can use `std::vector`, why not?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore, it's working indeed. I should have made a mistake when I first tried with vector. Thank you for your patient help!